# How to insert Liferay blogs entry programmatically

Tags: blogs, liferay-6

I use Liferay 6.0.6 and i need to insert the blogs entry programmatically from my custom Portlet or scheduled job.

I found the class **BlogsEntryLocalServiceUtil** but don't know how to use it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
Company company = CompanyLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyById(MY_COMPANY_ID);
Role adminRole = RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(company.getCompanyId(),"Administrator");
List<User> adminUsers = UserLocalServiceUtil.getRoleUsers(adminRole.getRoleId());

 //GET USER ADMIN
 User adminUser = null;
 for (User user : adminUsers){
     if (user.getEmailAddress().equals(MY_ADMIN_EMAIL)){
         adminUser = user;
         break;
     }
 }
 if (adminUser!=null) {
     long userID = adminUser.getUserId();
     long groudID = adminUser.getGroupIds()[0];

     PrincipalThreadLocal.setName(userID);
     PermissionChecker permissionChecker=PermissionCheckerFactoryUtil.create(adminUser, true);                                     

     PermissionThreadLocal.setPermissionChecker(permissionChecker);

     Calendar displayDate =CalendarFactoryUtil.getCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone(StringPool.UTC));

     boolean allowPingbacks = true;
     boolean allowTrackbacks = true;

     int actionPublish = WorkflowConstants.ACTION_PUBLISH;

     ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
     serviceContext.setWorkflowAction(actionPublish);
     serviceContext.setAssetCategoryIds(new long[]{category});
     serviceContext.setCreateDate(displayDate.getTime());

     serviceContext.getExpandoBridgeAttributes().put("key1", value1);
     serviceContext.getExpandoBridgeAttributes().put("key2", value2);

     serviceContext.setAddGuestPermissions(true);
     serviceContext.setScopeGroupId(groudID);

     //INSERT BLOGS ENTRY
     BlogsEntryLocalServiceUtil.addEntry(userID, title, content, displayDate.get(Calendar.MONTH), displayDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), displayDate.get(Calendar.YEAR), displayDate.get(Calendar.HOUR), displayDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE), allowPingbacks, allowTrackbacks, new String[]{}, serviceContext);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have addEntry method available in the class you mentioned i.e. BlogsEntryLocalServiceUtil, just pass the required parameters and you will be able to create a blog entry.

> but don't know how to use it.

For this, you can try to look into portal-impl folder of liferay source and find all the java sources available there to find how to implement them.

Comment: Thank you but i have found the solution. I wrote the code in previous post

Comment: Yeah! I know that you have posted the code, but you didn't mention how you came to this solution. My motto to answer this is to give a generalized answer so that other people can use any ***LocalServiceUtil in there portlets. Hopefully it will be useful for others. :)